# Switching to App in Dock

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows, I can swtich to the application that is opened in the taskbar using <kbd>Windows</kbd>  + <kbd>Number Key</kbd>. Is there a similar shortcut key in mac to switch to opened applications in Dock. Or is there a way to assign shortcut keys to open applications.

Use Case:

I want to switch between my opened Firefox and Terminal and Sublime Text using shortcut keys, instead of using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature built in. You have several options to achieve a similar effect yourself:

- Use a launcher, such as Quicksilver or LaunchBar. They'll learn your preferences or let you assign keys to certain applications, so that you can quickly switch between applications no matter what their Dock positions are by e.g. typing a hotkey and a single letter.
- Create scripts such as `tell application " Terminal"  to activate` in AppleScript editor. You can assign them keyboard shortcuts in [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/).
- Create *Automator* workflows with the *Launch Application* action for each of the programs, and assign keyboard shortcuts in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*.
- For *Terminal* specifically, you could use [Total Terminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com), a hud-style terminal.

---

If you want to access the *Dock item* at a specific position rather than a specific application, you can use UI scripting in AppleScript: Enable the keyboard shortcut to focus the Dock in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Keyboard & Text Input* and *Enable access for assistive devices* in *System Preferences » Accessibility*. Now you can create a script such as the following script, which (usually) activates the third Dock icon from the left:

```
tell application "System Events"
    # press Ctrl-F3
    key down control
    key code 99
    key up control

    # right arrow twice
    key code 124
    key code 124

    # enter to confirm
    key code 36

    # focus Dock again
    key down control
    key code 99
    key up control

    move left twice to re-set to original position
    key code 123
    key code 123

    # Escape to close
    key code 53
end tell
```

It's not a reliable solution though, as the Dock remembers the last focused element and requires you to reset the position afterwards. Your own use of the keyboard to access the Dock will interfere with this script.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will check the QuickSilver or Launchbar.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use scripts like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dock"
    click UI element 6 of list 1
end tell
```

Or just [assign shortcuts to applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-open-a-specific-application-on-os-x/20116#20116) directly.